# C# - If statement to dynamically determine which master page to use - MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages

I have two master pages in my C# MVC application. What I would like to be able to do is use one, or the other depending on the users 'role'. Something similar to this (obviously with a little more validation etc):

```
<% if(User.IsInRole("One")) { %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/One.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyApp.Data.ProductData>" %>
<% } else if { %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Other.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyApp.Data.ProductData>" %>
<% } %>
```

I've seen answers where this can be done to elements of a page, for example a menu, an image, etc. Is it possible to do it for the entire master page? In my situation, depending on the role, different css, images, colours will be used so it is necessary to use a different master page.

If anyone could help I'd be very grateful, or if anyone has any alternative (and probably better) solutions I'd also be grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using ASPX View in ASP.net MVC Application.
ASP.net MVC ASPX ( Webform) view still derive from Page class so you can use following code in 
your aspx view.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"  %>
<script language="C#" runat="server">
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            this.MasterPageFile = "~/Views/Shared/Site2.Master";
        }
        else
        {
            this.MasterPageFile = "~/Views/Shared/Site.Master";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change it dynamically via [ViewMasterPage.MasterPageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewmasterpage.aspx).

Comment: This is not a bad answer, but perhaps you can supplement it with a relevant code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the selection **in** your Masterpage file rather than selecting which masterpage file to use.